# Is that possible to update confluence page from Slack automatically?

Tags: slack-api, confluence

I'd like update/create a Confluence page from an auto-created message in Slack. Is that even possible?

Comment: If Confluence has an API: Sure.

Comment: Your question is way to broad in its current form, so I am voting to close. If you want to receive more substantial answers I would suggest reading this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask